# How to single click and turn to another page in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm writing this code for a school assignment, which I'm supposed to use pygame and display some text. I put those text in different pages, and if single click the screen, it will show the next screen.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
# defining the screen
SIZE = (1000, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
# define time
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#define button
button = 0
# define font
fontIntro = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman",30)
# define draw scene
def drawIntro(screen):
    #start
    if button > 0:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = fontIntro.render("Sigle click to start", 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(text, (300, 300, 500, 500))
        pygame.display.flip() 

    #page1
    if button == 1:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = fontIntro.render("page 1", True, (255, 255, 255))
        pygame.display.flip()
    #page2
    if button == 1:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = fontIntro.render("page 2", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (300,220,500,200))
        pygame.display.flip()
    #page3
    if button == 1:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = fontIntro.render("page3", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (200,190,500,200))
        pygame.display.flip()


running = True
while running:
    for evnt in pygame.event.get():
        if evnt.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if evnt.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            mx,my = evnt.pos
            print(evnt.pos)
            drawIntro(screen)

pygame.quit()
```

Though it is not working, can someone please help?! Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to [the example creating guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, it would be helpful if you described your problem more thoroughly than as `it is not working`.

Answer (score 2):

You define `button = 0` at the beginning, but never change its value in your main loop. In your `drawIntro` function, you check `if button > 0` or `if button == 1`
So obviously you never execute any of those `if` statements.

You need to catch the mouse button by calling `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` and figure how to switch correctly to the next page.

By the way, you also have `if button == 1` three times, which is not what you want I guess, because the `if` statements will be immediately executed as they are written, so your page 3 will be shown immediately. You need some counter to keep track of which page you need to show next time the mouse button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment the `button` counter when the user presses a mouse button.

The `drawIntro` function shouldn't be called in the event loop once per `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` event but in the main `while` loop. Also, change `MOUSEMOTION` to `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to increment the `button` once per click.

The conditionals in the `drawIntro` function are incorrect.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
SIZE = (1000, 700)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
button = 0
fontIntro = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman",30)


def drawIntro(screen):
    #start
    if button == 0:  # == 0
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = fontIntro.render("Sigle click to start", 1, (255,255,255))
        screen.blit(text, (300, 300, 500, 500))
    elif button == 1:  #page1
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = fontIntro.render("page 1", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (300,220,500,200))
    elif button == 2:  #page2
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = fontIntro.render("page 2", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (300,220,500,200))
    elif button == 3:  #page3
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        text = fontIntro.render("page3", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (200,190,500,200))


running = True
while running:
    for evnt in pygame.event.get():
        if evnt.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if evnt.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # Once per click.
            button += 1

    drawIntro(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```